# Why this page has horizontal scrollbar on mobile screen Safari and iOS browsers

Tags: html, css, ios

I am using latest Bootstrap to create website and I have annoying problem with horizontal scrollbar on iOS devices (both Chrome and Safari browsers). On Android devices or if I test responsive design on Chrome on Windows then everything is fine. The problem is iOS/mac platform.

The page in question is this: http://test.proteka.hr/catalog/akcije

But funny, the same page with fewer products (but it is the same template (markup)) doesn't have horizontal scrollbar. I think it must be something with the products HTML markup but I am not able to see what is causing this horizontal scroll.

http://test.proteka.hr/catalog/novo

^ This page doesn't have horizontal scrollbar on iOS or when testing on macOS Safari (iPhone).

I've tried adding this piece of CSS code so it is easier for me to debug this problem:

```
* {
    outline: 1px solid #f00 !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

But it seams that all of the elements are properly aligned within the viewport.

EDIT:
Also, please do not advise me to apply overflow-x: hidden on html and body tag beacuse I have sticky header that is not working properly if I set overflow-x property to hidden.

Comment: I would recommend using a basic debugging procedure of removing elements until you don't see the scrollbar. Then you know the last element was the one that caused the problem.

Comment: The width of the page seems to increase with the number of items in vertical list.  Check for right margins.